# Gravar uma array no Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando gravar algumas informações no *MySQL* através de uma `Array` obitda de uma execução externa, abaixo o código que estou usando:

```
$licencas = exec(escapeshellcmd($comando), $output);
reset($output);
while (list(,$line) = each($output)){ 
echo $line, "<BR>\n"; 
$sql= mysqli_query ($conexao,"INSERT INTO licenca (cnpj,dados, data) VALUES ('$cnpj', '$line', '$data')");
}
```

Está funcionando, porém quando armazena na tabela, ele deixa de gravar algumas linhas que foram obtidas, no echo aparece todas as linhas conforme eu preciso.

Quem puder me ajudar.

Muito obrigado.

Comment: Insira um `mysqli_error` e veja se retorna algo. `$sql= mysqli_query ($conexao,"INSERT INTO licenca (cnpj,dados, data) VALUES ('$cnpj', '$line', '$data')") or die(mysqli_error($conexao);`

Comment: Adicionei, apresentou essa mensagem!    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 's : 1', '2019-02-08 08:24')' at line 1

Comment: Dê um print na query que está executando, a mensagem informou que está com algum erro de sintaxe

Comment: Oi Pedro, dei uma pesquisada aqui e consegui resolver dessa forma: $licencas = exec(escapeshellcmd($comando), $output);
reset($output);
while (list(,$line) = each($output)){ 
echo $line, "<BR>\n";     $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conexao, "INSERT INTO licenca (cnpj,dados, data) VALUES(?,?,?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sss', $cnpj, $line, $data);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}      Será assim o melhor jeito?

Answer (score 1):

## Resolvi da seguinte forma:

```
//Executa o comando para verificar licença e armazena na variavel $line
$licencas = exec(escapeshellcmd($comando), $output);

reset($output);
while (list(,$line) = each($output)){ 

//Grava resultado da execução da execução no banco de dados
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conexao, "INSERT INTO licenca (cnpj,dados, data) VALUES(?,?,?)");

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sss', $cnpj, $line, $data);

mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode simplesmente utilizar o Serialization do PHP conforme a própria documentação.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

No momento de reutilizar você pode utilizar o Unserialization para retornar a array para o seu formato "real".

```
$serializedArray = serialize($array);
$unserializedArray = unserialize($array);
```

O seu código ficaria algo parecido com isso:

```
$licencas = exec(escapeshellcmd($comando), $output);
reset($output);
while (list(,$line) = each($output)){ 
echo $line, "<BR>\n"; 
$sql= mysqli_query ($conexao,"INSERT INTO licenca (cnpj,dados, data) VALUES ('$cnpj', '$line', '".serialize($data)."')");
}
```